# How can I write a function to modify a struct's member value without knowing the member's name ahead of time?

Tags: c++

Say I have a struct that has a bunch of member variables.  I want to write a function that will set the value of any of those members (along with a few other things, but I think that is beyond the scope of the question).  Something like (but obviously not) this:

```
struct A
{
  A() { /* do stuff */ }
  bool a1;
  bool a2;
  bool a3;
  void set_member(???);
  bool get_member(???);
};

A a;
a.set_member(a1, true);
bool value = a.get_member(a1);
```

Now, my first thought is to use an array instead of a bunch of named variables.  I would like to do that, but this is code that I would not like to touch in that way if I can help it (it is legacy).  It has a constructor so I'm not even sure if it will maintain it's binary serializablility characteristics since it is not a POD.  Even if it were a POD, I'm still not convinced as `a1`, `a2` and `a3` can have different alignment than that on an array of `bool`s.

So, going back to the original question, is there a way of doing this?  Perhaps with some template trick that I'm not aware of yet?

Comment: all members are booleans?

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't write individual set and get methods for each variable?  Is there something that you want to do that requires you do have a single get and set method?  Unless you are willing to return something like boost::any, or all of your member variables are of the same type, you're going to need more than one get method.

Comment: Why don't you use switch operator?

Comment: The question is code smell.

Comment: I spy, with my little eye, something beginning with "troll".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a pointer-to-member:

```
void set_member(bool A::*var, bool value)
{
    this->*var = value;
}

A a;
a.set_member(&A::a1, true);
```

A templatized version is straightforward:

```
template<typename T>
void set_member(T A::*var, T value)
{
    this->*var = value;
}
```

But I don't see the reason for doing this if you already know the name of the variable.

Comment: The reason is, there are other things that need to be done and they are repetitive, so I want to make a function to do the repetitive task.  It's not as simple as the get/set functions I described.

Comment: @DieterLücking What do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

If all contiguous members are the same data type, you could use pointer arithmetic:

```
void set_member(size_t var, bool val)
{
  *(&a1+var) = val;
}

bool get_member(size_t var) const
{
  return *(&a1+var);
}

A a;
a.set_member(1, true);
bool value = a.get_member(1);
```

But this can cause memory corruption or access violations if you use the wrong value of 'var'.

Comment: Data members of a class are not guaranteed to be continguous and even if they were this wouldn't be the way to go about obtaining them.

Comment: If the data members are all identical sizes, then won't they be contiguous?

Comment: This isn't said by the standard, or if it is, I have yet to see.